# html refresh bases on php variables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am fairly new to php/html and in the forum.Is it possible for a page to update its html part based on php variables?
In my case i have

```
    <form action = "" method = "post">
      <label>UserID  :</label>
      <input type = "text" name = "username" value="<?=$id?>" class = "box" readonly/><br /><br />
      <label>UserName  :</label>
      <input type = "text" name = "username" value="<?=$name?>" class = "box"/><br /><br />
      <label>Password  :</label>
      <input type = "text" name = "password" value="<?=$password?>" class = "box" /><br/><br />
      <label>UserType  :</label>
      <input type = "text" name = "usertype" value="<?=$privilege?>" class = "box" /><br/><br />
```

and i want the user to input a search(name)and if found fill the rest of the forms to be edited.I would like to avoid ajax/javascript and stick to php/html,switching pages also doesnt cut it(search on one go to second with same html code).Thanks a lot!!

Comment: yes, but without ajax you're doing a full-blown server roundtrip, which means you can rebuild the page any way you want. and note that ajax has nothing to do with JS. js is a programming language, ajax is simply an http request that happens to be initiated programmatically.

Comment: avoiding ajax/javascript when dealing with web pages is like saying you want to avoid using text-messaging and data on a smart phone. You can do it, but you're avoiding modern technology. Without it, web sites tend to be clunky.

Comment: Thanks for fast answering.My googling until now  plus the lack of any resource on the subject confirms your answers but the above project wont (and as u noted shouldsnt) make it on any real use webpage.Could you advice me on what method i could use to achieve that?(if its not crazy complicated to think or describe)

Comment: we're not here to help you design your system, or tell you what you should use. That's YOUR decision.

Comment: My understanding is that you want the form fields to appear based on the user input. The correct way to do this is by using Javascript. For example, you can hide some items, and then display them on condition using javascript. If you want to perform a search on your database from client side, then you are also expected to use AJAX/XmlHttpRequest... And don't worry, we're here (at least some of us) to help you design your system so feel free to ask any specific questions according to the guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for the help man.I can understand it might be disturbing to insist for help when not using the proper methods.You got my point right.My earlier and working approach was to get the input from the user sanitize it and pass it in a  _SESSION variable to a next page with all the forms filled and ready to edit.The only problem was that i had to restart browser on each new access.So now i am trying to find a way to design that on a single page but my knowledge gets me that far...Thanks for your help ,your time and your willingness to help..

Comment: One more question and i hope i dont break the rules with that.Is it possible to livesearch a mysql table  to match the displayed html values and dont query the database over and over?

Answer (score 0):

This guy asked to update HTML page based on php variables, not based on user input

If you want to update HTML page dynamically based on user input, the answer is javascript, eg

```
<form action="" method="post">
<label>UserName :</label>
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="<?=$name?>">

my.js
$("#username").on("blur", function(){
  if ($(this).val() == "liakos") alert("welcome back");
});
```

However you do not need any javascript if you want to display page dynamically according to php variable, eg:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<label>UserName :</label>
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="<?=$name?>">
<?php
    if ($name == 'liakos') {
        echo 'Hey dude, what is up!';
    }
?>
```